# How to programmatically import OSM data with osmosis in Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, openstreetmap, postgis

I've found the osmosis libs in maven 3 repository which I inserted into the pom.xml of my project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openstreetmap.osmosis</groupId>
        <artifactId>osmosis-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.44.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And now I try to import a *.osm.pbf data file into the PostGres / PostGIS database. The commentaries for the main method inside the Osmosis class says that you should write your own pipelines.

Does anyone know a example how to implement a complete functionality for importing data?

I've tried the Osmosis.run(args) method, but this seems not to accept my arguments.

**Additional notes:**

My approach looks like this so far:

```
   String args[] = { "--read-pbf file=" + DOWNLOAD_STUTTGART_PBF, "--log-progress",
                     "--write-pgsql host=\"localhost\" port=\"5432\"" + 
                     "database=\"myDatabase\" user=\"admin\" password=\"pw123\"" };

   Osmosis.run(args);
```

The output looks like this:

```
07:36:53.901 [main] INFO  o.j.p.standard.StandardPluginManager - plug-in started - org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.plugin.Core@0.43.0.1-49-gb18e1e9-dirty-SNAPSHOT
Okt 22, 2015 7:36:53 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFORMATION: Preparing pipeline.
```

No data is imported into the database. Unfortunately documentation is non existing, or I just cannot find the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Now I got the solution:

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator;

String args[] = { "--read-pbf", "file=" + workingDir + DOWNLOAD_STUTTGART_PBF, "--log-progress",
            "--write-pgsql", "host=localhost:5432", "database=myDatabase", "user=admin",
            "password=pw123" };

Osmosis.run(args);
```

The clue is to deliver all parameters separately in the array.

Also you need to include some more dependencies:

```
<!-- OSM Osmosis Importer Libs -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openstreetmap.osmosis</groupId>
  <artifactId>osmosis-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.44.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openstreetmap.osmosis</groupId>
  <artifactId>osmosis-pbf</artifactId>
  <version>0.44.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openstreetmap.osmosis</groupId>
  <artifactId>osmosis-pbf2</artifactId>
  <version>0.44.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openstreetmap.osmosis</groupId>
  <artifactId>osmosis-osm-binary</artifactId>
  <version>0.44.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openstreetmap.osmosis</groupId>
  <artifactId>osmosis-extract</artifactId>
  <version>0.44.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openstreetmap.osmosis</groupId>
  <artifactId>osmosis-hstore-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>0.44.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openstreetmap.osmosis</groupId>
  <artifactId>osmosis-dataset</artifactId>
  <version>0.44.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openstreetmap.osmosis</groupId>
  <artifactId>osmosis-pgsnapshot</artifactId>
  <version>0.44.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I wish the developers would also deliver excellent documentation besides the excellent code.